# Apache Spark (PySpark) handling null values when reading in CSV

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read in flight data from the Department of Transportation. It is stored in a CSV, and keep getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`

I have tried setting the `nanValue` to the empty string, as it's default value is `NaN`, but this hasn't worked.

My current code is:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('local') \
    .appName('Flight Delay') \
    .getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
    StructField('Year', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('Month', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('Day', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('Dow', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('CarrierId', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('Carrier', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('TailNum', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('Origin', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('Dest', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('CRSDepTime', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('DepTime', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('DepDelay', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('TaxiOut', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('TaxiIn', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('CRSArrTime', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('ArrTime', IntegerType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('ArrDelay', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('Cancelled', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('CancellationCode', StringType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('Diverted', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('CRSElapsedTime', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('ActualElapsedTime', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('AirTime', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('Distance', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('CarrierDelay', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('WeatherDelay', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('NASDelay', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('SecurityDelay', DoubleType(), nullable=True),
    StructField('LateAircraftDelay', DoubleType(), nullable=True)
])

flts = spark.read \
    .format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
    .csv('/home/william/Projects/flight-delay/data/201601.csv',
         schema=schema, nanValue='', header='true')
```

Here is the CSV I'm working with: http://pastebin.com/waahrgqB

The last row there is where it breaks and raises the `java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`

It seems that some numeric columns are empty strings, while others are just empty. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure it only breaks at the last data row? The other data rows are fine? --- Maybe you can also make your script complete, so we can copy-paste it. Right now some `import` statements are missing I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the numeric type column having an empty string (with "" instead of blank data).

Then one option is to read the data as StringType column, then convert that column type to your relevant type (ex: int). So that it wouldn't impact other column data.

```
StructField('CRSDepTime', StringType(), nullable=True),


flts.withColumn('CRSDepTime', flts['CRSDepTime'].cast("int")) \
    .printSchema()
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to KiranM's suggestion, I was able to find a solution. I let Spark infer the schema(everything is set as a String), and then manually set the columns I want to be numeric.

Here is the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import (SQLContext,
                     SparkSession)

from pyspark.sql.types import (StructType,
                           StructField,
                           DoubleType,
                           IntegerType,
                           StringType)

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('local') \
    .appName('Flight Delay') \
    .getOrCreate()


flts = spark.read \
    .format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
    .csv('/home/william/Projects/flight-delay/data/merged/2016.csv',
         inferSchema='true', nanValue="", header='true', mode='PERMISSIVE')


flts = flts \
    .withColumn('Year', flts['Year'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('Month', flts['Month'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('Day', flts['Day'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('Dow', flts['Dow'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('CRSDepTime', flts['CRSDepTime'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('DepTime', flts['DepTime'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('DepDelay', flts['DepDelay'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('TaxiOut', flts['TaxiOut'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('TaxiIn', flts['TaxiIn'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('CRSArrTime', flts['CRSArrTime'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('ArrTime', flts['ArrTime'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('ArrDelay', flts['ArrDelay'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('Cancelled', flts['Cancelled'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('Diverted', flts['Diverted'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('CRSElapsedTime', flts['CRSElapsedTime'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('ActualElapsedTime', flts['ActualElapsedTime'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('AirTime', flts['AirTime'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('Distance', flts['Distance'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('CarrierDelay', flts['CarrierDelay'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('WeatherDelay', flts['WeatherDelay'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('NASDelay', flts['NASDelay'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('SecurityDelay', flts['SecurityDelay'].cast('int')) \
    .withColumn('LateAircraftDelay ', flts['LateAircraftDelay '].cast('int'))
```

Maybe I could put that into a loop, but I'm going to run with this for now.